# What is the permission group 'others' in Linux file system?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

Is the group 'others' required for file permissions? Aren't 'user' and 'group' only groups try to read/write/execute file at any given moment?

Comment: All who is not defined in groups | users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others is not technically a group. Other is everyone that is not the owner or in the group. For example, if you have a file that is root:root then root is the owner, users/processes in the root group have group permissions, and you are treated as other.

Comment: Hence, are those who have not created the file or those who have not been given ownership of the file or those who are not in group called as others?

Comment: yes. those not the owner or in the group named are others

Answer (score 1):

File permissions are categorized into three *sections*:

- the *owner* of a file may do something with the file (read/write/execute)
- members of a *group* may do something with the file (read/write/execute)
- *others* (everybody else) may do something with the file (read/write/execute)

With the `chmod` and `chown` commands we can change mode (access rights) and ownership of a file.

- Ownership means who (which user and which group) owns the file
- access mode means what they can do with that file

A file with mode

```
-rwxr-xr-- alice users ....
```

can be

- read, written, and executed (first three `rwx`) by the *user* `alice`
- read and executed (second three `r-x`) by all members of the group `users`
- just read (third three `r--`) by all other users

So `others` simply means everybody that is not (necessarily) the owner or group-member of a file.